# Redux Form: is there a way to capture any form change events?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a feature that's built where I retrieve information from a database and populate them into redux form. However, what I'm stuck at is I want to save a "save changes" button appear whenever the user makes **any** changes to the forms so that this button can appear and overwrite their entry in the database.

For example: I have a button:

`View Links`

Now when any changes in the form happens, this changes to

`Save Changes`

How would I go about doing something like this? I was wondering if I could maybe attach a dispatch to the forms' `onChange` so it can add a `changed: true` state. Otherwise, is there a way that to achieve something like this with redux-form?

Comment: I am just curious about the question that is why I am asking this. Simply you need to change the information of the db using a redux-form right? If it is so! Do you have a REST API? If you have a GET method and POST or PUT method that is possible to do.

Comment: @DushanRandika That is correct, however that would be the next step which I know how to handle. Please see my edit for a better example!

Comment: Sure! That is going to be a good implementation. Using an onChange event and keep a state to check whether the field has changed or not is a nice combine. But the problem is if you are doing something like this every single time Save Changes will be appeared that means so many db calls right?

Comment: @DushanRandika Not necessarily! The DB call will only be when the user clicks on "Save Changes". Otherwise changes will not be saved. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Use these boolean Properties `dirty` and `pristine` that redux-form gives your decorated redux-form component.

**Pristine** is true when form values are unchanged and **dirty** is true when form values have been changed.

You can then use them and ReactJs if-conditions to show other components as you see fit.

Example;

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const SimpleForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, dirty, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="firstName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="lastName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
        {dirty &&
          <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
            Save Changes
        </button> 
        }
        {pristine &&
          <button type="button" disabled={submitting} onClick={reset}>
            View List
        </button>
        }
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple', // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);
```

You can see I use `{dirty && component_to_render}` to only render that component when the form has received any changes and using

```
<button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting}> Submit </button>
```

to disable the button when nothing has been changed or while the form is submitting.

Above is a code sample (with minor edits) from [basic redux-form example](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/simple/) and my full edited code is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oqrm11wwmz)